# Animate() só funciona na primeira transição

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou criando um carousel infinito que deveria ficar animado entre as transições, porém o evento `.animate()` só funciona na primeira transição, no restante fica completamente estático, sem animação.

Código:

```
var next = function(){
    var left = parseInt(ul.css('left')) - (size + rest + settings.margin);

    ul.stop(true, true).animate({'left' : left}, settings.speed, function(){
        $('> li:last', ul).after($('> li:first', ul));
        ul.css({'left' : (size + rest + settings.margin) * (-1)});
    });

    return false;
}

var transition = null;

var init = function(){
    transition = setInterval(function(){
        next();
    }, settings.delay)
};

init();
```

Obs: caso eu remova o fix `.css()` da posição, o carousel se mantem animado, porém logicamente a ul estará indo à esquerda até que desapareça.

O que há de errado?

Comment: Podes recriar o problema no jsFiddle? Há muitas variáveis no código em cima que não se vê de onde vêm. Dificil saber o que o código faz assim.